# Passing literal attribute values to angular js directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how attribute values work in AngularJS directives. No matter what I try, literal attribute values come out as `undefined` when I try to use them within the directive controller.

Say in my HTML I envoke a directive like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive reference-attr='referenceVal' literal-attr='literalVal'></my-directive>
</div>
```

`referenceVal` and `literalVal` are both defined in my controller, like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.referenceVal = 'This was passed by reference';
    $scope.literalVal = 'This was also passed by reference, but should have been literal';
}
```

And I try to pick them up in my directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            referenceAttr: "=",
            literalAttr: "@"
        },
        template: '<div><p>Reference:{{referenceAttr}}</p><p>Literal:{{literalAttr}}</p></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            alert("ref: " + $scope.referenceAttr + ", lit: " + $scope.literalAttr);
        }
    };
});
```

The output looks fine:

```
Reference: This was passed by reference
Literal: literalVal
```

But the alert message is crap:

```
ref: This was passed by reference, lit: undefined
```

You can try it out yourself with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1883/)

Any idea why `literalAttr` is undefined in the directive scope at this point?

Comment: Ancient Angular versions, like 1.0.1 used in the Fiddle had some problems (?) with interpolated directive attributes. Recent versions exhibit the expected behaviour. See [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD9D2/)

Comment: Ah, thanks Nikos, a newer version of Angular JS fixes it (d'oh). Do you want to make this an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the oldest versions of Angular, e.g. the 1.0.1 used in the fiddle. Recent versions exhibit the expected behaviour.